# Translation C99 code to Z3, subtle details

Tags: python, z3

I am encountering some subtle details that I don't understand quite well. I am developing a tool to remove dead code, assuming the following example:

```
int main(){
    if(1==0){
        neverexecutes();
    }
}
```

I translate that to an AST ([pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser)), and when I encounter the if condition `1==0` I translate it to Z3 using the following method:

```
def evaluate_ast(self, node: c_ast.Node):
        """Translates a c_ast.Node to a z3 predicate."""
        typ = type(node) 
        if typ == c_ast.BinaryOp:
            leftnode = self.evaluate_ast(node.left)
            rightnode = self.evaluate_ast(node.right) 
            
            if node.op == '&&':
                return And(leftnode, rightnode)
            elif node.op == '||':
                return Or(leftnode, rightnode)
            elif node.op == '==':
                return leftnode == rightnode 
            elif node.op == '<':
                return leftnode < rightnode
            elif node.op == '<=':
                return leftnode <= rightnode
            elif node.op == '>':
                return leftnode > rightnode
            elif node.op == '>=':
                return leftnode >= rightnode
            elif node.op == '!=':
                return leftnode != rightnode
            elif node.op == '/':
                return leftnode / rightnode
            elif node.op == '+':
                return leftnode + rightnode

        elif typ == c_ast.Assignment and node.op == '=':
            leftnode = self.evaluate_ast(node.lvalue)
            rightnode = self.evaluate_ast(node.rvalue) 
            
            return leftnode == rightnode
        (...)
```

The `1==0` is translated to `k!0` and the solver answers `sat`, which is incorrect.

If I change the treatment of C99 equality like this:

```
elif node.op == '==':
     return And(leftnode == rightnode)
```

it works, I assume I have the same problem with all binary operators. What am I missing here? A system with only `False` shouldn't be `unsat` ? I think the `k!0` is just a translation to some false value in Z3.

I think this also graphics a little better my question:

```
>>> from z3 import * 
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(False)
>>> s.check()
unsat
>>> s.reset()
>>> s.add(1==0)
>>> s.check()
unsat
>>> s.reset()
>>> s.add(Bool(1==0))
>>> s.check()
sat
```

What's the difference between `False`, `1==0` and `Bool(1==0)`?

Comment: This is most likely a problem with automatic casts. Try stepping through it in the debugger to see which of those values actually get translated to Z3 expressions. My guess is that `Bool(1==0)` is a Python (non-zero) pointer to an object and the Z3
 API doesn't know what to do with it, so it creates a symbolic constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Bool` takes a name and makes a symbolic value out of it. You need to use `BoolVal` instead. In these cases the `sexpr` method is your friend for debugging purposes:

```py
>>> from z3 import *
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(1==0)
>>> print(s.sexpr())
(assert false)
```

The above is OK, because the `add` method is smart to treat values correctly. You could've wrapped it around `BoolVal` for the same effect:

```py
>>> from z3 import *
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(BoolVal(1==0))
>>> print(s.sexpr())
(assert false)
```

But see what happens if you wrap it around `Bool`:

```py
>>> from z3 import *
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(Bool(1==0))
>>> print(s.sexpr())
(declare-fun k!0 () Bool)
(assert k!0)
```

And that is the essence of your problem. (Looks like z3 is coming up with an internal name `k!0` since `1==0` isn't a valid SMTLib name here. Which adds to the confusion.)

Note that z3py has similar functions for `Int`/`IntVal`, `BitVec`/`BitVecVal`, `Real`/`RealVal` etc. that you have to be careful with similarly.

This is one of the weakest points of z3py unfortunately: Due to Python's untyped nature, different functions try to interpret all sorts of inputs you can provide and they are sometimes inconsistent and it can be very hard to detect and debug such issues. If you suspect something is off printing `s.sexpr()` is your best friend. (A similar recent bug was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621990/checking-sat-using-check-with-assumptions-rises-attributeerror-bool-object/62625436?noredirect=1#comment110779871_62625436) and subsequently fixed, for instance.)

Comment: Yeah, I am the same guy who asked that other question :) apart from [this](https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html) guide is there any other python oriented that you would recommend? Or should I dive into the implementation?

Comment: That's probably your best bet. I also like https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm for basic info, but you're probably well beyond that by now! Best of luck.